# Installing pymzml on Anaconda issues

Tags: anaconda

I am trying to install pymzml through anaconda cmd prompt (conda install -c bioconda pymzml)

but the following error appears:

( PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- pymzml
  any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Seems like that's pretty clear... you have to find a channel that has that package for the OS you're using... What isn't clear to you?

Comment: I tried, it appears to be a windows issue and works fine in Linux apparently. Thank you anyway.